# Android is reading string as blob

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have following text in SQLITE database in TEXT field

> The exact date of his birth is not known. The consensus of opinion, however, is that he was born around 580 B.C He was younger than the his friends.
>
> He belonged to a noble family.

When I read this from DB and add to `ArrayList<String>` I get following error message

```
14): unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string
14): unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string
14): unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string
14): unknown error: Unable to convert BLOB to string
14): Closing Cursor
```

I am confused why its becoming a blob? here is how I am reading this

```
String select = "SELECT heading,text FROM details WHERE chapter_id = \'" + tocIDX + "\'" ;

Constants.c = Constants.myDataBase.rawQuery(select, null);



int headingIndex = Constants.c.getColumnIndex("heading");
int headingTextIndex = Constants.c.getColumnIndex("text");

Constants.c.moveToFirst();
    if (Constants.c != null) {


        if (Constants.c.isFirst()) {

            int i = 0;

                /* Loop through all Results */ 

                do {

                        i++;
                        if(Constants.Debug){
                            Log.d("toc", "Row # " + i);}

                        try{
                              headingIndex.add(Constants.c.getString(headingIndex));
                            headingTextIndex.add(Constants.c.getString(headingTextIndex));          


    } catch (Exception e) {if(Constants.Debug){Log.d("toc", e.getMessage());}   }


                } while (Constants.c.moveToNext());
```

Highly appreciate your help

Comment: have you read the sqlite data types? If you come from a MySQL background you are going to be surprised.

Comment: I am new to database...just basic knowledge. I read data types for sqlite but can't understand why my text field is converted to blob. If so how to I convert it to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the data type of heading and text columns are defined as BLOB. you can substring the data to get  You have two way.

- Approach-1) use SUBSTRING to get string from the BLOB data.
- Approach-2) If possible use VARCHAR instead of BLOB as data type

Comment: NAVICAT is showing TEXT for the fieldname "texT". its not blob

Comment: Okay this what I have done and worked for me. Can't accept it as an answer coz don't have enough points to submit an answer                             byte[] blobs = Constants.c.getBlob(headingTextIndex);
String blobString = new String(blobs);
                            Constants.headingTextIndex.add(blobString); // saving string into ArrayList<string>

Comment: Had the same problem, Abid's answer worked....but why is think happening??? Must be a bug